# Create two separate tables for entities separated by one attribute?

Tags: database-design

Suppose I have a table called `Apple_Jobs`.

It defines jobs coming from the `Apple_Server`.

Now suppose I have another server called `Orange_Server`

Should I

- modify the existing `Apple_Jobs` table with an attribute called `Origin` defining where the job came from - `AppleServer` or `OrangeServer`.

*OR*

- make a separate `Orange_Jobs` table.

With the first option, I would need to modify certain applications existing querys and stored procedures to only include `AppleServer` origin jobs, with the second option I would not need to modify any stored procedures.

The structure of each table is the same.

Comment: I know its a lot of work now but it is worth modifying your code to handle a field rather then create a new table and then create new sprocs to handle that table.  Your code will be more lean and mean as well as clean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself creating tables called
AppleServer
OrangeServer
PearServer

and even PomograniteServer

you have a serious problem, to fix it create a field called type with avalaible values such as "Apple", "Orange", "Pear" and the notorious "Pomogranite".

Do not keep adding tables it will make your life misreable.
If you need a specific fruit server you then query the one table:

```
SELECT blah FROM MyTable WHERE Type="Orange"
```

Answer (score 1):

Always aim for maximum [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (where it makes sense, of course).  In your case, I would suggest you create a `ServerType` (look-up/meta) table, which will contain a list of your server types (e.g. Orange, Apple, Watermelon, etc).  Then add a `ServerTypeID` column to your `Jobs` table, which will be the foreign key to the `ServerType` table.